# SSRS populate column of one dataset from another dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to SSRS so I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do.

I have a tablix that is populated using Dataset1.  One column of the tablix I'd like to populate using Dataset2.  Dataset2 just returns a value based on a parameter passed in from the Dataset1 row.

I've tried using a report parameter, however, it seems to always populate the column value the same for all the rows.

Example:

Table is bound to Dataset1 that returns a bunch of car information along with a car id.

Dataset2 needs to take in the car id and it returns a value:

Select amount
from carTable
where id = [id passed in]

I need the value returned stored in the table populated by Dataset1.
Both datasets use different datasources and that is why I need to do it like this.

Comment: Have a look at the "lookup" function in SSRS. It's not clear from your question if it is a single value that you are after or match detailed row based on a column!

Comment: Thanks Harry.  Basically I want to pass in the column value of the table to Dataset2 and Dataset2 will return a single value.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment.. displaying the value is simple enough.

If your second dataset is returning only one value and you want to display that in your tablix.. you simply need to aggregate it and specify the dataset name..

Assuming your dataset 2 is called ***Dataset2*** and the column returned is called ***column***

use the following in your tablix :

```
=max(Fields!column.value,"Dataset2")
```

you can use max, min, fist..

Comment: I put in an example in my original question of what i'm trying to do.  I hope its more clear.  Please take a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to achieve.. would be good to show an image of what you want to show on the report..